# Is it a good idea to tie Java process to jenkins so that It can be monitored?

Tags: java, linux, jenkins

I had an independent java process running in linux. I wanted it to be monitored constantly. So I installed jenkins and started the process from  jenkins. Jenkins keep showing the process as ongoing through which I know that the process is running.

Though it works as per my requirement, I wanted to know if this is a good approach? All the java process will be tied to the jenkins session, will it cause any memory issue?

Comment: Very broad question ... be more specific: what kind of "monitoring" do you envision? Do you want to kill processes, restart them, ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Jenkins was designed, in the first instance, to do much more than monitor processes, it's not at all "wrong" to use Jenkins for the sole purpose of process monitoring. If Jenkins fits your use case, then use it.

Jenkins is designed to handle a large number of memory intensive processes, so I would doubt that you would easily run into memory issues with just monitoring java processes. However, it sounds like your concern is with the fact that the java processes may be long running, in which case I suppose it's possible to have memory issues; but without more specific information, it's hard to say. You can, of course, modify the jenkins jvm configurations (heap, perm gen, ec) to better fit your needs if the out-of-the-box configurations don't suffice.

Comment: Exactly what I was talking about, the process are forever running, and they might be memory intensinve. But if we fix heap size accordingly then nothing else should be of concern right?

Comment: As long as the heap size etc, are set properly, it should be ok. Memory should be even less of a concern though, if you are using [jenkins eternal job monitoring](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs). That way jenkins isn't responsible even for running the job - only for monitoring - and thus memory should be much less of a factor.